# merging exchange and iCloud contacts in iPad

Tags: contacts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exchange contacts do not appear in iCloud](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33247/exchange-contacts-do-not-appear-in-icloud)

I have sent my Gmail contacts to my iPad via Microsoft Exchange. I now want to back them up to my iCloud account but they reside as a different group in the iPad contacts. 
How can I move or merge them to my iCloud group in contacts to sync with iCloud?

Many thanks, Harry

Answer (score 0):

There was [a similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33247/exchange-contacts-do-not-appear-in-icloud) recently. [This Apple support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5058) includes the quote:

> Data stored with iCloud will not interact with your Microsoft  Exchange data, while likewise your Exchange data will not interact with iCloud data.